# How do I differentiate an improper integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I would like to differentiate a function of the type $\int_x^\infty f(x, t) dt$ with respect to $x$ ($f$ real or complex valued). Does differentiation under the integral sign apply? What are better methods to differentiate this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

Comment: I know about differentiation under the integral sign, that's why I mentioned it in my question.

Answer (score 2):

One may use [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

> $$
> \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right )=b'(x) \cdot f\big(b(x),x\big)  \,-\,a'(x)\cdot  f\big(a(x),x \big)+ \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x}(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t 
> $$

giving here, [with appropriate hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement),

> $$
> \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_x^{+\infty} f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right )=-\, f\big(x,x \big)+ \int_x^{+\infty}\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x}(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t .
> $$

Comment: How did $b'(x)\cdot f(b(x), x)$ vanish here, considering that the upper bound  $b(x)=\infty$?

Comment: Please have a look at the hyperlink above.

Comment: I did, but didn't get how the part with $b'(x)$ vanish.

Comment: Here $b(x):=M$ which is a constant with respect to $x$ (thus $b'(x)=0$), but this is true for any constant  $M$ as great as we want ($M>M_0$) giving the second identity above.

Comment: Can we treat infinity as a constant with respect to a variable, as $\infty$ is not a value?

Comment: Yes if we can switch limits : an improper integral is defined with a limit, differentiating is defined with a limit, so if one is allowed to switch the order of limits, then we are done... that's why I had written 'with appropriate hypotheses'...

Comment: Do you happen to know a reference for the proof of the dominated convergence theorem-corollary result?