# Differentiating infinity wrt any variable: is it zero or undefined?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, infinity

I want to further the discission from this question: [Can you take the derivative of a function at infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747593/can-you-take-the-derivative-of-a-function-at-infinity)

Basically I am interesting in this expression:
$\frac{d}{dx}(\infty) \text{ or } \frac{d}{dx}(-\infty)$

**Are those expressions zero or undefined?** Software like TI-89 calculator and Mathematica will treat infinity as a constant so the expressions become zero (and hance defined).

*My motivation for asking*: IF the expressions equal zero and is defined then working with improper integrals will become much simpler by use of for instance Leibniz rule for integration.

The answer to this question [How do I differentiate an improper integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760917/how-do-i-differentiate-an-improper-integral) might *imply* that differentiating infinity with respect to x is zero.

Comment: Have I misused the word 'expression'?

Comment: This is undefined. Derivatives are defined for functions, not for anything you want. This question is the same as asking "what is $\frac{d}{dx} (\mathrm{Hello!})$?"

Comment: See this [basic differentiation rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360807/derivative-with-respect-to-constant)

Answer (score 4):

Infinity is not a number. $\infty x$ Is not defined in basically every context. The basic definition of a derivative does not deal with things that are not defined.